# How to add custom message from Key Value pair to the model validation error messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, model-validation

Hi I just got question where i need to assign the error messages for my model validation from key value pair, i tried with the ModelState.AddModelError("TaskName","Error Message"), but i need some thing more reliable and Error messages are residing in database.

So any luck from my friends out there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whats wrong with `ModelState.AddModelError("TaskName","Error Message")` and why don't you think its reliable?

Comment: @Stephen sorry , every time i need to use this logic to so i thought it would increase code, so is there any way where i can read it from key value pair during model creation itself.. to ErrorMessage Property?

Comment: What sort of messages are you talking about. Why can't they be handled by ValidationAttributes on your properties? Perhaps an example might help so we can understand the issue.